# Is it possible to use dynamic parallelism on the GPU on OSX?

Tags: macos, opencl, gpu

I'm trying to implement an application that requires dynamic parallelism, but OSX seems to support only OpenCL 1.2, which does not have that. CUDA isn't supported on OSX devides without nVidia, obviously. Is there any way to use dynamic parallelism on the GPU of a Macbook?

Comment: Apple stopped investing in OpenCL a few years ago, they're putting all their weight behind Metal. I can't answer your question, but if it is possible to do what you ask on macOS, you will only find it in Metal - I suggest you research whether that API supports the feature and/or possibly edit & retag this question to be about Metal compute kernels.